What does "as to" mean in "to request to be quiet, **as to** start (a meeting)"
A definition from the Collins dictionary for the phrase "call to order" states:
"to request to be quiet, as to start (a meeting)"
Does "as to" in this context mean...
as to:
in American English

as if to (Collins dictionary)

? In other words, is a meeting following this action required or optional?

Yes, as [if to] = by way of / in order [for example] to start a meeting.

I'd say that "as if to start" means not starting, but almost like it. "As to start" means in a way that begins, or like when you open.

as to starting a meeting.

This is dictionary jargon. You can remove "as" without changing the meaning, except "as" clarifies that this isn't the only context in which the word can be used, just a canonical one that other uses allude to.
That is to say, if 90% of things that are called to order are meetings, the other 10% are analogous to meetings. The dictionary is telling you this in precise language that doesn't depend on whether the case in question is actually a meeting or not.
This is restricted to a very formal, near-legalistic mode of speech.

as introduces the context in which the phrase is used; "as to start a meaning" can be informally paraphrased  "like when starting a meeting".

"to request to be quiet, like when starting (a meeting)"

For example:

The head of the town council called the meeting to order.

The head of the town council formally started the meaning, perhaps by hitting a wooden mallet a couple of times on a block, or speaking into a microphone and saying the magic words "I'm calling this meeting to order", both of which everyone understands as a signal that it's time for them to stop chatting.
P.S. You've seen acting credits on movies, for example, "with Harrison Ford as Han Solo". There, "as" heads a phrase that presents a role. Here, in the dictionary entry, "as" heads a phrase specifying the role that "call to order" plays on the 'speech stage', as it were, namely "to start a meeting".

I'd add that "as to" isn't a single unit with its own definition here; you replaced "as" with "like" and "to start" with "starting".

@chepner: Agreed. to is the infinitive marker there, and as is being complemented by an infinitival clause. But I find that describing the syntax doesn't always result in a better understanding of the meaning.

@TimR: It's true that "as to" isn't a single syntactic unit, but chepner's point is that it isn't a single semantic unit, either!

@ruakh I have removed to from inside the quotation marks, which I did not intend to indicate a  semantic unit but rather a semantic cooperation.

The meaning is that the speaker is requesting that people cease side conversations and pay attention to whatever the meeting is about.
The meeting is required, it is the entire point.
